# JSON deserializing to C# types

Tags: c#, json

I have got following JSON that should be deserialized to C# class:

> {"status":"error","messages":[{"level":"error","key":"InvalidTokenError","dsc":"Invalid
>   token"}]}

So I have a questions what is the kind of type should be

> [{"level":"error","key":"InvalidTokenError","dsc":"Invalid token"}]

?

Is this array, list or class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) to get the types of the JSON.

JSON:

```
{"status":"error","messages":[{"level":"error","key":"InvalidTokenError","dsc":"Invalid token"}]}
```

Here is the classes generated for your JSON:

```
public class Message
{
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string dsc { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<Message> messages { get; set; }
}
```

for JSON:

```
[{"level":"error","key":"InvalidTokenError","dsc":"Invalid token"}]
```

Type:

```
public class Message
    {
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string dsc { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this site](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class Message
{
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string dsc { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<Message> messages { get; set; }
}
```